# task_done() called too many times

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio, greenlets

Hi stack overflow folks!

I'm currently getting this error every once and awhile in my Flask/Socketio app and I haven't a clue where to begin debugging or what it means:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 536, in run
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 167, in writer
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/engineio/socket.py", line 37, in poll
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/queue.py", line 470, in task_done
ValueError: task_done() called too many times
```

There seems to be no rhyme or reason to when it happens either.

Comment: It will be better if you show us your code.

Comment: That's the thing, I don't know where in my code this is happening since the traceback doesn't reference my code. It references modules I'm using.

Comment: can you share your `main.py` ? it's not easy to understand till we get the enough information. or you may share with us which module you used and how do you use that

Comment: This is a pretty odd error to get, it may be caused by a concurrency bug in the gevent `JoinableQueue` class. If you can, I suggest you switch to eventlet and see if you get it there too. If eventlet works reliably, then a bug in gevent's implementation of the queue is a good theory. If you also get it with eventlet, then I guess I'll have to look harder at my code, as that would point to something on my side that is wrong.

Comment: I'll try converting over to eventlet someday. Awesome to have a response directly from you though!

Comment: I am currently with the same error with using  gevent on flask/socketio. When using eventlet (with or without monkey_patch()) communication over sockets do not work, only http requests. Did you found the solution?